# ¿Cómo mantener la posición estática de una tabla al hacer zoom al navegador?

Tags: html, css, html5, table

Estoy realizando un mapeo de un mapa de un país, este mapeo consiste en establecer varios puntos en cada estado, lo realice mediante una tabla y funciona correctamente, pero al momento de disminuir el zoom se me mueve la tabla y los puntos se mueven o mas bien las celdas se alargan.

Esta es la imagen sin zoom
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la imagen al disminuir zoom:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier sugerencia  de como resolver esto seria de gran ayuda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si creaste tu tabla, deberías hacerla responsiva poniendo una clase en la etiqueta table

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <!-- Contenido -->
        <table style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Campo 1</th>
                <th>Campo 2</th>
                <th>Campo 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Valor 1</td>
                <td>Valor 2</td>
                <td>Valor 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Valor 1</td>
                <td>Valor 2</td>
                <td>Valor 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Valor 1</td>
                <td>Valor 2</td>
                <td>Valor 3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </table>
</div>
```

No se si te ayude. Espero que si, saludos

Comment: Colega, podrías decirme cómo hiciste la tabla como un mapa? Quisiera hacer algo similar. Un saludo